# Why are flickity css not being loaded in Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, flickity

So I am trying to incorporate [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) carousel in my Angular app. I think technically it should working fine, the issue that stops it from making it work the way it should is that none of the css from `flickity.css` seems to be loading. I was hoping someone might have an idea why that might be the case.

I added `flickity` to my app by running `npm install flickity`.

Thereafter, in my `component`, i added `flickity` as such:

```
import * as flickity from 'flickity';
```

Next I initialised everthing:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      this.carousel = document.querySelector('.container');
      console.log(this.carousel);
      this.flick = new flickity(this.carousel, {
        imagesLoaded: true,
        wrapAround: true
      });

      var imgs = this.carousel.querySelectorAll('.item img');
      console.log(imgs);
      var docStyle = document.documentElement.style;
      var transformProp = typeof docStyle.transform == 'string' ?
        'transform' : 'WebkitTransform';

      this.flick.on('scroll', function() {
        this.flick.slides.forEach(function(slide, i) {
          var img = imgs[i];
          var x = (slide.target + this.flick.x) * -1 / 3;
          img.style[transformProp] = 'translateX(' + x + 'px)';
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Essentially all the `js` seems to be working fine but none of the inherent `flickity` is being rendered, meaning everything from the flickity viewport, buttons etc.. hence the whole thing won't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `flickity` css file to your angular.json imports like so

**angular.json**

```
// ...
"styles": [
 // path to flickity css
 // I just made this up so you will have to double check the path to the css file
 "node_modules/flickity/dist/flickity.min.css"
]
```

Please note: You will have to restart your project once this has been added for changes to take effect.

**OR**

As per the flickity docs you could just include this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
```

in your `index.html`