# Flickity CSS Styles not Being Applied

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3, flickity

Pretty simple issue, I think it may be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067691/why-are-flickity-css-not-being-loaded-in-angular) but in Vue instead of Angular.
The CSS styling I try to apply to my Flickity carousel doesn't render for my Vue 3 app. In the IDE the styles are greyed out, but when I edit them in my browser via the inspection (like changing the carousel-cell width, for example), it works fine.

Am I missing a CSS import somewhere to make my CSS file correctly alter the appearance of my rendered layout in a browser?

```html
<template>
    <div class="col d-block m-auto">
       <flickity ref="flickity" :options="flickityOptions">
       </flickity>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .carousel-cell {
      background-color: #248742;
      width: 300px; /* full width */
      height: 160px; /* height of carousel */
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
      /* position dots in carousel */
    .flickity-page-dots {
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    /* white circles */
    .flickity-page-dots .dot {
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      opacity: 1;
      background: white;
      border: 2px solid white;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you'd like to override some of the `Flickity.vue` component's styles from the parent.

With [*Scoped CSS*](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html) (i.e., from `<style scoped>`), the styles are applied only to the current component and not its children. If you want to stick with scoped CSS, you can target the dynamic children with [`:deep()` (`::v-deep` in Vue 2)](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)
around your selectors, as shown below.

Since the `Flickity.vue` component's own scoped styles for `.carousel-cell` have higher CSS specificity, the parent component would need to bump up its specificity (e.g., by using `!important`).

```html
<style scoped>
:deep(.carousel-cell) {
  background-color: red !important;
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 160px !important;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

/* position dots in carousel */
:deep(.flickity-page-dots) {
  bottom: 0px;
}
/* white circles */
:deep(.flickity-page-dots .dot) {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  opacity: 1;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
</style>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-flickity-styles-from-parent?file=src/App.vue)

Alternatively, you could just use a plain/unscoped `<style>` block. Removing the `scoped` attribute would be enough.

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-flickity-styles-from-parent-xq3nhe?file=src/App.vue)